# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html FastAPI

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I tried to use fastapi for rendering html files. I don't know why app can't find the template.

```
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse


app = FastAPI()


templates = Jinja2Templates("templates")

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', context={'request': request})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ4cx.png)

Comment: Is there an `index.html` file under the `templates` directory?

Comment: Yes. There is "templates" directory on the same level to main file. And there is "index.html" file in "templates directory".

Comment: Not according to the error message - add the proper details, including the name and location of the file you've included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not the root directory
use this:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates("app/templates")
```

instead of this:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates("templates")
```